# How can I return custom hibernate validation message in my controller with i18n?

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf, hibernate-validator

I use Spring Boot and Hibernate validator and Thymeleaf.

Everything is ok when I validate a form item.

But after I add a verify code, I check if it's wrong code;

When the code is wrong I add a new `FieldError` and return it.

```
if (!captchaCode.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getVrifyCode())) {
    bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("user", "vrifyCode", "{singup.vrifycode.error}"));
}
```

And of course I defined the `singup.vrifycode.error` in my ValidationMessages.properties file.

But at web page it just show `singup.vrifycode.error` not the correct value.

But in my model everything is ok like this:

```
@NotBlank(message="{signup.email.null}")
@Email(message="{signup.email.fomart}")
private String email;
```

How can I show correct value in my page?

If I can not, tell me how can I get the correct value(by locale) in ValidationMessages_en_US.properties, ValidationMessages_ja_JP.properties and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we must understand that there are two different validations API:s in the mix here; first the Spring validation with `BindingResult` and `FieldError` classes, and then the Bean Validation API (Hibernate Validator) with the annotations. The good news is that Spring translates validation errors from Bean Validation API, so these work together.

One difference is that Spring doesn't use `{` and `}` around its translation keys (in spring called *codes*), keep that in mind.

For i18n you must use the 7-arguments constructor of [FieldError](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html):

```java
new FieldError("user", "vrifyCode", user.getVrifyCode(), false, new String[] {"singup.vrifycode.error"}, null, null)
```

Note that the translation should be in the *Spring* messages file, because it is Spring validation we are working with here.

Comment: Thanks very much for your good answer. I've show error message correctly, But as you say, It can only show the message defined in Spring message file.I want to know if I can use Hibernate Validator message file(ValidationMessages_en_US.properties), change source code is OK(change the validation under the Hibernate Validator controll). PS:I check the verify code in my Controller because I can't check it in the Bean Validation API . Thanks!

Comment: @YOUNG Custom code can be used to read the Hibernate message file, but if the purpose is to have all validation messages in the same place, then put all in Spring messages file, that works out-of-the-box.

Comment: If it means there is no way to put all the message in Hibernate message file? even change my source code.